# How do I use @Valid with Spring MVC's @RequestBody parameters?

Tags: spring, validation, data-binding, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm having an issue with using `@Valid` on a parameter to a handler method on my `@Controller`. My code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value=BIBBLE_BOBBLE_URI_PATTERN + "/widgets", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Widget saveNewWidget(
        @PathVariable final String username,
        @PathVariable final String bibbleBobbleName,
        @Valid @RequestBody final Widget widget,
        final BindingResult results,
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response)
```

where `Widget` is the class for one of my domain objects. I'm using the `@RequestBody` annotation to indicate that the payload of the request maps to `widget` (in my tests, the requests are JSON, though Jackson is on my classpath so I could also use XML).

As you can see, the `BindingResult` parameter follows directly after the `Widget` parameter, but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!
```

How do I apply the `@Valid` annotation to a `@RequestBody` parameter and then get the results?

P.S. I'm using `annotation-driven` to handle wiring up the controllers, do content-negotiation, etc.

Comment: I'm learning all this still, **but**, try naming the attribute `@ModelAttribute("xyz") Widget widget`.

Comment: @DecaniBass will that address the problem of it not binding any data that I mentioned in my comment on @craftsman's answer?

Comment: I know its a old POST, but is it working for you? I am using Spring 3.2. The binding works, but not @Valid. Question posted here [http://stackoverflow.com/q/16174990/668650]

Comment: remove parameter ```final BindingResult results,``` from controller method

Comment: If you are using Kotlin with Spring Boot, then you must use `@field:Email`, `@field:NotNull` etc. on the respective fields to make sure that `@Valid` works. For information follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515094/kotlin-and-valid-spring-annotation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Spring 3.1? It is a newly added feature in Spring version 3.1. Please see [Validation For @RequestBody Method Arguments](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1569)

Comment: This is welcome news indeed, but I'm stuck on 3.0.5 at least until 3.1 goes final. Thanks for the pointer, though.

Comment: 3.1 is final / released/ out in the wild now. :)

Comment: The link just says annotate with "@valid" and "@requestbody", but I get the same error and am using 3.1 :-(

Comment: please see http://blog.42.nl/articles/leveraging-the-spring-mvc-3.1-handlermethodargumentresolver-interface

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue in spring 3.0 and it is fixed in 3.1 M2.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6709

If you are using spring 3.0, based on some threads and extensive reading, here is the best approach for this problem. An aspect oriented approach so that we can back out when you upgrade it to the version of spring which fixes this issue.

An aspect which intercepts calls to method which uses @RequestMapping annotation and for each parameter which has @Valid annotation on it, call the corresponding validator in the aspect.