# kotlin and @Valid Spring annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, kotlin

I have an entity:

```
class SomeInfo(
        @NotNull @Pattern(regexp = Constraints.EMAIL_REGEX) var value: String) {
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

And controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some-info", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Id create(@Valid @RequestBody SomeInfo someInfo) {
       ...
    }
```

`@Valid` annotation doesn't work.

It seems Spring needs a default parameterless constructor and fancy code above becomes in something ugly (but working) like this:

```
class SomeInfo() {

    constructor(value: String) {
            this.value = value
        }

        @NotNull @Pattern(regexp = Constraints.EMAIL_REGEX) 
        lateinit var value: String

        var id: Long? = null
    }
```

Any good practice to make it less wordy?

Thanks.

Comment: You're saying that Spring needs a parameterless constructor but the working code still has just a single parameter constructor.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Edited.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Seems Spring needs these annotations to be applied to a field. But Kotlin will apply these annotations to the constructor parameter. Use `field:` specifier when applying an annotation to make it apply to a field. The following code should work fine for you.

```
class SomeInfo(
    @field:NotNull
    @field:Pattern(regexp = Constraints.EMAIL_REGEX)
    var value: String
) {
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

Comment: Curiously, how'd you come up with that?  Reflection on the resulting data model?

Comment: Idk how Michael found this but there's some references to the issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16297 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11343#issuecomment-351430911

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative to Michal's answer, annotating the getter also works.

```
class SomeInfo(
    @get:NotNull
    @get:Pattern(regexp = Constraints.EMAIL_REGEX)
    var value: String
) {
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

The annoying part is, that not using @get: or @field: will annotate the constructor parameter. This is still valid kotlin code (so you don't get an error). It's just useless in these use cases.

Comment: I tried it and didn't get it working. Do I need some extra configuration or it just works?

Comment: No, should work out of the box. I am using it in a spring project, so I have the spring-kotlin package which essential modifies spring classes to be automatically "open" classes and "open methods" if they are spring annotated. That might be a site effect that kicks in.

Answer (score 9):

If you use IntelliJ to convert Java to Kotlin, the `@Valid` annotation in the Spring Controller method may eventually be attached to the type, instead of the variable. This would break the validation.

For example, the convertion could result in

```
@PostMapping
public Id create(@RequestBody someInfo: @Valid SomeInfo) {
    ...
}
```

This is not validating. The `@Valid` has to be moved to a variable like this:

```
@PostMapping
public Id create(@RequestBody @Valid someInfo: SomeInfo) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also your rest controller should be marked by `@Validated` annotation

Answer (score 1):

For function validation of primitives:

```
@Validated
class MyClass() {
    fun myFun(@Valid @NotEmpty @Size(min = 3, max = 30) name: String) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are validating email addresses you could also write it like so:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email
import javax.validation.constraints.Size

data class User(
    val id: Long,
    @field:Size(min = 2)
    val firstName: String,
    @field:Size(min = 2)
    val lastName: String,
    @field:Email
    val email: String,
   ..)
```