# Kotlin + Spring Boot default value for Int field from JSON

Tags: spring, kotlin

I am writing simple CRUD with Kotlin + Spring Boot + Hibernate and came up with the issue:

I have a field in `User` class called `age` and type `Int`

```
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.Size

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long,

        @NotBlank
        @Column(unique = true)
        @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
        val username: String,

        @NotBlank
        @Size(max = 50)
        val firstName: String,

        @Size(max = 50)
        val lastName: String?,

        @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
        val age: Int
)
```

Then I have post request which creates a user

```
@PostMapping
fun post(@RequestBody user: User): User {
    log.debug("POST: {}", user)
    return userRepository.save(user)
}
```

The problem is that when I miss `age` field in JSON it doesn't respond with 400 error, but defaults to `0` instead.

How do I make this field required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515094/kotlin-and-valid-spring-annotation),
also thanks to @Adam Arold for showing best practices.

I created new `UserDTO` class:

```
import ai.leavingstone.flywayspringdemo.domain.User
import javax.validation.constraints.*

data class UserDTO(
        private val id: Long = -1,

        @field:NotBlank
        @field:Size(min = 1, max = 100)
        private val username: String,

        @field:NotBlank
        @field:Size(max = 50)
        private val firstName: String,

        @field:Size(max = 50)
        private val lastName: String?,

        @field:NotNull
        private val age: Int?
) {

    fun toUser(): User = User(
            id,
            username,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            age!!
    )

}
```

Before none of data validation annotations worked, after adding `@field` prefix it's working fine. `@NotNull` on `Int` is also working and default value for `id` field as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a bigger problem is that you are using the same class (your entity) for multiple purposes. This makes this class very unflexible since you can't adapt it to the needs of your REST endpoint and to the needs of Hibernate as well.

What I'd do instead is having a boundary between the two (something like [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) would suggest to do):

```
data class UserDTO(val id: Long?,
        var username: String?,
        var firstName: String?,
        var lastName: String?,
        var age: Int?) {

    fun toUser() = User(
        id = id ?: signalError(),
        username = username ?: signalError(),
        firstName = firstName ?: signalError(),
        lastName = lastName ?: signalError(),
        age = age ?: signalError())

    private fun signalError() : Nothing = throw IllegalArgumentException(
        "Missing parameter in UserDTO.")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Valid @RequestBody user: User` for the method parameter so spring is going to validate the given body. This should be done by default but just in case write it down and it´s better for new workers etc.

Also @`Size` annotation does not support primitives or numeric vars. It just verifies a length of `String`, `Array`, `Map`, `List`... So just annotate it with `@Min` and `@Max`. So the default Value of 0 would not be valid anymore.

Also for a nullable object to validate you can use `Integer` instead of `Int` so you can check just `@NotNull` if you want negatives or 0 be valid, too without getting default value 0.

Comment: It's not working and can't figure out why. Do I need some configurations of dependencies ?

Comment: Kotlins type `Int` can´t be null so if it isn´t present but getting filled when parsing the body it is allways 0. So it is valid with `NotNull`. But if you use `@min @max` it should work.... I got no more idea, sry. It worked for me like this.