# Kotlin + Spring Boot + @Valid not worked child object's internal object

Tags: spring-boot, validation, kotlin

Here's the code:

```kotlin
data class Father(
        @Valid
        val sonExamResult: Son.ExamResult
)

data class Son(
        val examResult:ExamResult
){
    data class ExamResult(
            @field: Size(min = 0, max = 100)
            val math:Int,
            @field: Size(min = 0, max = 100)
            val physicalEducation:Int
    )
}
```

How can I verify a data structure similar to the above? I try to pass a `-1` to `ExamResult.math`, but nothing happend.

My native language is not English, I am very sorry for the word error.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The @Size uses for lists and other collections, where min and max parameters restrict its size. You need to use @Max and @Min and data class

```
data class Father(
    @field:Valid
    val sonExamResult: Son.ExamResult
```

)

```
data class Son(
    val examResult:ExamResult) { data class ExamResult(
        @field:Min(0)
        @field:Max(100)
        val math:Int,
        @field:Min(0)
        @field:Max(100)
        val physicalEducation:Int
)}
```

see also: [kotlin and @Valid Spring annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515094/kotlin-and-valid-spring-annotation)

Comment: I have no problem with a simple data structure like the one you wrote.
The problem is in the properties of the inner class.

Comment: It's the same. Use `@field:Valid` and `@Min` and`@Max` instead of @Size.
Edited the code from the answer above. With the code above the validation does not pass for invalid data.