# Gradle Spring mvc validation data class recursive Kotlin

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, kotlin

I need to create a recursive validation to be able to validate PizzaCreate Object and base attribute in recursive mode using Kotlin. The test  should return 400 but  it returns 200 ok (Base name size must be greater than 2):

```
data class Base(@field:Length(min = 2, max = 100) val name:String)    

data class PizzaCreate(
    val id: Long,
    @field:Length(min = 2, max = 100) val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val price: Int,
    @Valid val base: Base
```

)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pizza")
class PizzaController(val pizzaService: PizzaService) {

@PostMapping
fun post(@RequestBody @Valid pizza: PizzaCreate) = pizzaService.addPizza(pizza)

}
```

---

```
  @Test
fun `should add pizza `() {

    val pizza = easyRandom.nextObject(PizzaCreate::class.java).copy(id = 1, name="aaa", base = Base(""))
    val pizzaOut = PizzaOut(id=1,name=pizza.name,description = pizza.description,price = pizza.price)

    `when`(pizzaService.addPizza(pizza)).thenReturn(pizzaOut.toMono())

    webTestClient.post()
            .uri("/pizza")
            .bodyValue(pizza)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isBadRequest
            .returnResult<PizzaOut>().responseBody
}
```

Comment: base.name is `aaa` so it's correct. Try with base.name equal `a`, then you should see 400.

Comment: base = Base("") base name is "" not aaa (aaa is the pizzaCreate name value). I am trying to force base name recursive validation

Answer (score 1):

Validation on Base should be `@field:Valid val base: Base` instead of `@Valid val base: Base`

`field:` specifies the annotation is applied on the field not construc

ref:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35853200

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36521309

Comment: It works like a charm. I thought field: wasn't a must with recursive validation. A lot of thanks for your fast response.